# How to delete "local_storage" Internet Explorer with Windows Command

Tags: php, codeception

I am currently using Codeception with Selenium Server. 
My problem is, that everytime I run a test, there are few elements like the favorite list, that still contain objects that I dont want.

My goal is to delete the local_storage of the internet explorer and edge, every time i run the test.

Is there a CMD command that deletes them?
I already used following code, but it doesnt delete the local_storage:

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255
```

Comment: Why CMD? Selenium can run JS - so why don't `localStorage.clear();
sessionStorage.clear();` before run tests?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code with the codeception extension, that means I am writing the test in the own codeception language, I cant just add JS commands. Moreover I am just starting the selenium .jar so I dont really know how to run JS Code

Comment: I'm not familiar with codeception, but 2 minutes searching leads me to documentation and this method: `$I->executeJS("window.alert(arguments[0])", ['Hello world']);` - maybe it should help.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me, I looked in the docs but haven't seen it before, my failure. Have a nice day.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I've pasted it as answer, so anybody could find it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of CMD commands just add clearing js code to Yours tests:

```
$I->executeJS("localStorage.clear(); sessionStorage.clear();");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a lot easier way to do it. In the acceptance suite just add for the internet explorer the following:

```
capabilities:
    ie.ensureCleanSession: true
```

Hope this will help some of you